# Macで2つのディレクトリを双方向で同期したい

Tags: macos

Macで2つのディレクトリを双方向で同期したいのですが可能でしょうか。

手動で何かしらのone-lineコマンド、またはアプリのボタンを押すと同期が実行される、と言うものを探しています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイルの双方向同期をする CLI ツールとしてはたとえば [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) が知られています。Homebrew をお使いであれば `brew install unison` でインストールでき、`unison dirA/ dirB/` で同期できます。

同様のツールは他にもいくつか知られており、たとえば [osync](https://github.com/deajan/osync) というものもあります。

英語での Q&A に他のツールの例も載っているのを見つけました：

- [Two way sync with rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2936627/5989200)
- [bi-directional sync with rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256128/211480)